# How did the European public school system originate?

Tags: europe, education

Are there any good sources for learning about the history of education in Europe?

I am particularly interested in learning about the origins of the public schooling system, as it seems they should likely have had a huge impact on society as a whole and I have no real idea of where it came from.

*I tried to do a little searching, although most results I could find online seemed very America-centric.*

Comment: History.stackexchange [frowns](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3866/1401) on source requests unless they are for a canonical source.  Stack Exchange assumes that each question has an authoritative answer; source requests are list questions where the answers are inherently subjective and tend to produce more argument than education.  Note that _all_ answers should be supported by sources, so it is generally possible to avoid the problem by asking for the information you want and assuming that the answer will be sourced.

Comment: I see two potential core questions here: either (1) How did the public school system originate in Europe? or (2) what impact did the European public school system have?

Comment: Apologies if the question is a bit vague. I would say that I am more interetsed in the former, how public schools originated. I tried to do a little searching, although most results I could find online seemed very america-centric.

Comment: [Factory Schools](https://qz.com/1314814/universal-education-was-first-promoted-by-industrialists-who-wanted-docile-factory-workers/) [History of Education](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/freedom-learn/200808/brief-history-education) [sutori](https://www.sutori.com/story/history-of-teaching-and-learning-in-europe--15atd7Nki8DC5NWCiiHFrK3z) (the last looks most useful)

Comment: I mean ... *technically* putting the words "Are there" at the front of the question makes is a yes or no question, rather than a list question. Sometimes that's good enough, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thank you, these seem like a great place to start.

Comment: This presumably varies from country to country. I am passingly familiar with the history of the Italian public school system (itself a descendant of the pre-unification Piedmontese one), but it's only one of many.

Comment: Yes it is not the same from one country to another. France has its own history of public education. The main feature is Jules Ferry's laws in 1881 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Ferry_laws) establishing that the most tiny village should have a school with state-paid teacher(s). These laws were intended to fight against the influence of Catholic Church through its school system. The result was that in some places of France like Britanny, many villages had two primary schools , one public ("laic system"), the other one Catholic. [Continued]

Comment: (Continued: about France) In a second step, the [1905 laws](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2141325?seq=7#metadata_info_tab_contents) was a big blow on the Catholic teaching system (expulsion of teaching orders)

Comment: Some keywords that may be helpful with regard to the German public education system: The "Generallandschulreglement" (roughly "general countryside school regulation") passed 1763 under Fredrick the Great, which layed the groundwork for broad compulsory schooling. The education reforms of Wilhelm von Humboldt around 1810, which meant to provide every child with a humanistic education, but only really worked for higher schools and universities (and the social classes who could go there). And the emergence of the "dreigliedriges Schulsystem" ("three-pronged school system") in the 19th century.

Comment: Admittedly confusingly, in the UK **"public school"** relates to fee-paying "private" - ie not State - schools - think Eton and Harrow. The schools most people attend, funded by the State, are - State schools. Apologies for British idiosyncrasy! :-)

Comment: Are we talking about elementary or higher levels? Also, joining the others: Europe is a continent with many countries...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I would say I'm most interested in elementary level schooling in Ireland, although I imagine this might have a strong influence from the british history too.